# Adding hyperlink to Pandas Data Frame Items using Flask

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, flask

I am currently working on a page that present a pandas data frame. The table displays the over arching information. What I am wanting to do is make one of the columns either click-able or a hyper link. When a user clicks this item, it brings them to a new page showing more details for that line. How can I do that? 
Help please!
My python code is this

```
datasource = pd.read_csv( 'Donnees.csv' , encoding='latin-1' , sep=',' , dtype=object )
datasource[["AGENCE","MATRICULE","NOMS","CATEGORIE","CLASSIFICATION"]].head(5000)
```

I want to make the column Matricule as a link.
Looking for some advice on this. Thank you